# History of the Three Word Slogan

Tags: rhetoric

What's the history of the three word slogan in Politics? I'm aware of individual cases like "strong and stable" but was it ever as prevalent as it is now? It would be good to know if it happens in other languages/countries as well

Here are some examples of three word slogans in the states:

- Build the wall
- Four more years
- Lock her up
- Drain the swamp
- Keep them out
- Yes we can

and in the UK:

- Brexit means Brexit
- Get Brexit done
- Taking back control
- Wear a mask, Protect the NHS
- Hands, space, face

Comment: See also: Tony Abbott in Australia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "older than feudalism", perhaps "older than dirt" (to use the tvtropes terminology).  In Latin the phrase is "omne trium perfectum", and Ceasar said "Veni, vidi, vici". The French revolution had "Liberté, égalité, fraternité". The Afghan motto of its army is "خدا، وطن، وظیفه "

It is prevalent in other languages, and has been used in classical rhetoric since at least the time of Cicero.

The short slogans of three single sylable words also fit into a 4/4 rhythm         with a rest to mark the end of the slogan making it good for repetition and as a cheer.